# How can I use group by in SQL query on Stimulsoft Reports?

Tags: sql, report, stimulsoft

I need use group by or somethings else to show 1 time row in report file

It's my report image with this query

```
SELECT 
    jobcard.code AS code1,
    jobcard.name AS name1,
    nvl(masterpm.id, 0) toal 
FROM 
    jobcard 
LEFT JOIN 
    masterpm ON jobcard.id = masterpm.jobcard_id 
             AND masterpm.id IN (SELECT masterpm_id FROM cbmmasterpm)
```

[image: image as report]

If you look at the screenshot, you can see PM-BUI--FM-1سال-0001 repeat 3 time with 3 different value as toal

Now I want my report show anythings like in blow image

[image: image as final report]

How can I do that?

Thanks guys for helping

Answer (score 0):

You should add a Group Header and set its Conditions with Name1.